# Import My Own Function into Azure Timer Trigger

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, import, python-import

[Picture of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiEwi.png)

If you look at my code you can see I am trying to use my created function, send(message), to send a message. However, I am unsure how to import my file, which you can see on the left, SMSpy. Can anyone tell me how I can properly import my file, Thanks!

Comment: Please put the code in your issue description.  No screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If SMSpy has a class use

**One time call:**
Call it once with an instant object created.

```
import SMSpy
SMSPy.<classname>().send()
```

**Multiple Calls:**
Create an object and call

```
import SMSpy
Obj = SMSPy.<classname>()
Obj.send()
```

**If no class:**

```
import SMSpy
SMSpy.send()
```

Comment: Thank you, I am getting closer, but  I get the error: Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SMSpy'. could it be the location of my file SMSpy.py?

Comment: It gives another error calling NEWAFFIRMATIONS not a real module

Comment: Sorry about that, it was supposed to be ```import NEWAFFIRMATIONS.SMSpy```

Comment: I now get the error no module named ‘NEWAFFIRMATIONS’

Comment: This usually works for me in pycharm and it should work here too. I'm not sure why you get this error.

Comment: Yeah not sure what’s wrong either my solution was just to paste the function in my timer as well, badly written code but it works for now